# Combine two time range to one from table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have below two columns in availability table in my mysql database. Say, it has below data.

```
userid  start     end    date
   2    08:00   09:00   2018-06-20
   2    09:00   16:00   2018-06-20
   2    18:00   21:00   2018-06-20
   2    10:00   02:00   2018-06-21 
..
..
```

Now, I would need continuity time range of user's availability per day such that is available from 8:00 to 16:00 and then 18:00 to 21:00. How can I do this? Can this be done in mysql query itself? If not then how can I do in php.

End result :

```
userid  start     end    date
   2    08:00   16:00   2018-06-20   [Combined two rows]
   2    18:00   21:00   2018-06-20
   2    10:00   02:00   2018-06-21
```

I searched many things but didn't find any answer for this. Please help me and give me idea how I can do this.

Comment: what is the type of start and end columns?

Comment: This is untested, so I'm not posting it as the answer. You want to do something along the lines of: SELECT
  userid,
  a.date,
  a.start,
  COALESCE(b.end, a.end) AS end
 FROM
  availability AS a
  LEFT JOIN availability AS b ON a.userid = b.userid AND a.date = b.date AND a.start = b.end

Comment: Almost @flip need grouping on the min start :) see my answer

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach:

```
-- sample data
create table t (
   userid integer,
   start varchar(5),
   end varchar(5),
   date date
);

insert into t values 
(2, '08:00', '09:00', '2018-06-20'),
(2, '09:00', '16:00', '2018-06-20'),
(2, '18:00', '21:00', '2018-06-20'),
(2, '10:00', '02:00', '2018-06-21');

-- query:
select t1.userid, 
       min(t1.start) start, 
       coalesce(t2.end, t1.end) end, 
       t1.date
  from t t1 left join t t2 
             on    t1.userid=t2.userid 
             and t1.end = t2.start 
             and t1.date = t2.date
group by t1.userid, coalesce(t2.end, t1.end), t1.date
order by t1.userid, t1.date, start;
```

See it working here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/674fa/1

Comment: I got one issue with this. If I has three data as below, it didnt work when rows in table as 8 to 9, 14 to 16, 9 to 14.

Comment: Can you update your questions with such scenario please?